# Giving an user-runnable application special permissions in Linux

Tags: linux

Is it possible for an application to access files that a regular user cannot, while being runnable by the same user?

I am working on a hacking themed game that will be an entire Linux system, which allows the user to use programs to "connect" to hackable systems. Of course this will all happen on the system itself through programs that I write and preload to the system.

I plan to give users root permissions as a reward for finishing the game so they can see how the game is made, but I would prefer that they cannot access the game files before that.

I plan to write the programs in Java, but I am willing to use other languages if this is not possible in Java.

Comment: Look for setuid permissions for your program

Comment: Ah, that's it. I knew there was some easy way that I've overlooked. Thank you!